# Python - Unsure how to roll up row values within a column into a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is an example:

df1:

```
X Y Z
1 a cat
1 a dog
2 b hi
2 b hello
2 b hey
```

The final df should look like this.

df2:

```
X Y Z
1 a [cat, dog]
2 b [hi, hello, hey]
```

I'm really stuck and I'm having trouble even approaching this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df.groupby(['X', 'Y'])['Z'].apply(list)
```

returns

```
X  Y
1  a          [cat, dog]
2  b    [hi, hello, hey]
Name: Z, dtype: object
```

**Edit**: can just apply `list` instead of `Series.tolist` as @timegb suggests in the comments.